# Objective C delegates and class methods vs instance methods

Tags: objective-c, delegates, class-method, instance-methods

There is a similar question to mine on the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562515/how-to-use-delegation-or-pass-messages-from-class-methods)
but it doesn't quite answer my query.

I am setting a helper class for Facebook (follows the delegation pattern) . An example of one of the class methods would be:

```
+ (void)openSession:(id)delegate;
```

This method calls a the Facebook `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions` method which expects a completionHandler block. Would it make sense to call the delegate method, say `sessionStateChanged` in the block as follows?

```
[delegate sessionStateChanged];
```

Or is it better to use instance methods for the Facebook helper class and call the delegate using `[self.delegate sessionStateChanged]` in the completionHandler block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both methods i.e. using class and instance methods. Any of them will do, though to follow the proper delegation pattern I believe using instance methods is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off with a block parameter rather than a delegate as a parameter if it is just for a single callback.

`+ (void)openSession:(void (^)(void))sessionStateChangedBlock`

That way you don't have to worry about defining a delegate protocol.

If you want to use a delegate, you will have to define a delegate variable at the class level. You can't use `[self.delegate sessionStateChanged]` because you are saving the delegate as a class variable. `self` is only available in an instance of the class.

Comment: I understand this is a solution but were I to use the delegate pattern rather than the block pattern, which of the ones I mentioned makes more sense?

Comment: Edited answer to answer to your question about how to invoke the delegate.

Comment: @Fruit-Geek Why was my question down-voted? I know that `self` is only available in an instance class that is not my question. I just need to know whether it is better to use the class method and pass an `(id)delegate`parameter to it (the delegate passed adheres to the FacebookHelperDelegate protocol) and use it like so `[delegate sessionStateChanged]` or to use instance methods and call the protocol method with parameter `(id)delegate` as follows:
`[self.delegate = delegate];`
[self.delegate sessionStateChanged]` Thanks